# How to finish queue if leave hover jQuery

Tags: jquery, hover, queue

I've made this script with help of the jquery API documentation, and everything is working fine.

Except one thing, I want to finish the current event(queue) if you leave the hover. Every ball should turn transparant again if you leave the certain div. I've been searching for quite a while to make this happen, but it didnt help me .

Maybe its a stupid question and there is 1 line of code that needs to be added. But i'm hoping you could help me with this!

here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v84L4/1/)

And here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#hulp").hover(function() {
        $("#first").delay   ( 100 ); 
        $("#second").delay  ( 200 );
        $("#third").delay   ( 300 );
        $("#fourth").delay  ( 400 );
        $("#fifth").delay   ( 500 );
        $("#sixth").delay   ( 600 );
    $("#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth, #sixth").queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.addClass("red");
            that.dequeue ();
    });
        $("#fifth").delay   ( 1000 ); 
        $("#sixth").delay   ( 800 );


    $("#fifth, #sixth").queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.removeClass("red");
            that.addClass("blue");
            that.dequeue();     
    });
        $("#fifth").delay   ( 1200 ); 
        $("#sixth") .delay  ( 1000 );

     $("#fifth, #sixth")    .queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.removeClass("blue");
            that.dequeue();
            that.clearQueue();
    });
});
$("#hulp2").hover(function() {
        $("#first").delay   ( 100 ); 
        $("#second").delay  ( 200 );
        $("#third").delay   ( 300 );
        $("#fourth").delay  ( 400 );
        $("#fifth").delay   ( 500 );
    $("#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth").queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.addClass("red");
            that.dequeue ();
    });
        $("#first").delay   ( 1400 ); 
        $("#second").delay  ( 1200 );
        $("#third").delay   ( 1000 );
        $("#fourth").delay  ( 800 );
        $("#fifth").delay   ( 600 );


    $("#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth").queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.removeClass("red");
            that.addClass("blue");
            that.dequeue();     
    });
        $("#first").delay   ( 2200 ); 
        $("#second").delay  ( 2000 );
        $("#third") .delay  ( 1800 );
        $("#fourth").delay  ( 1600 );
        $("#fifth") .delay  ( 1400 );

   $("#first, #second, #third, #fourth, #fifth").queue(function() {
        var that = $( this );
            that.removeClass("blue");
            that.dequeue();
            that.clearQueue();
            that.finish();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of ending hover with  }); add below code after }

```
,function(){
    $('.helpen').nextAll('div').stop(true,true).removeClass('red blue');

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v84L4/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works. I still notice a small thing though maybe you could help me with. If you hover, then leave, then hover again within a short amount of time, its still a little buggy. Could you help me out with that perhaps too?

Comment: Like it doesnt completely shutdown the queue, it just hides it.

Answer (score 0):

Work with `on`:

```
$('.fuuu').on({"mouseenter": function(){
        //do something
    },"mouseleave": function(){
        //do something else
    }});
```